# In drupal 7 will I loose webforms if I disable then enable the webform module

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

If I disable the webform module in drupal 7 site I expect to not have access to the webforms themselves but is the content deleted or will I regain access when I enable the module again?

Comment: I've had cases where doing "apt update" on postgres caused all the local databases to get deleted. Regardless of what "should" happen, make backups and plan for the worst case.

Comment: does node export count as a backup?

Comment: a simple rule of thumb: will **you** be able to use it to restore to a properly working system? how easily?

Comment: Check .install file , datas are deleted on disable instructions to reset no ?